# Lenovo Y700 15-ISK headset microphone and internal microphone not working on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headset

Hi as you can read from the title I am unable to get my headset's mic and internal mic to work with Ubuntu 20.10. The headset's mic and the internal one works on both Windows 10 and Manjaro so it is a Ubuntu-specific problem. Is there someone with the same problem who succeeded in solving it? The laptop is a Lenovo Y700-15ISK 80NV.

I have already tried "adding options `snd-hda-intel model=alc233-eapd`" in the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. I have also tried with other models' names instead of `alc233-eapd` but I was only able to get the internal microphone to work. So the headset's microphone didn't work with any model's name.

I have also updated my kernel just in case but that did not make a change.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is completely speculative. I am by no means a linux Pro and i am actually just here to ask a similar question later.

Ubuntu usually ships with ALSA and Pulseaudio.

First of all i would check if my pulseaudio and alsa servers are running.

PulseAudio:

```
pactl list
```

ALSA:

```
aplay -l
```

Both will give an error if the sound system is not running. ALSA will be loaded with the kernel, PulseAudio will be started later. If this was not the case we can start PulseAudio manually from the terminal with:

```
pulseaudio [options]  ## option -D starts the daemon
```

If everything is running and the mic is listed somewhere but the mic is still not working, then you maybe should update to the new pulseaudio 14. Because the support for gaming headsets is better with the new pulseaudio version and by the looks of it you are using a gameing Laptop, so i assume you are also using a gaming headset. But i cant help you with the update to version 14. Because that is why i am here too. If i get an answer i will update this answer as well.

You definitely should tell us which Headset you are using.

Comment: It is a normal old headset from Trust. Nothing special. It always worked with manjaro.

Comment: Ok, I have just now switched to Ubuntu, and the headset's mic works but the internal one does not lmao... This without modifying the file I cited in the post.